# Forgot Password Form using AWS Cognito

Tags: javascript, amazon-cognito

I am implementing a logic of forgot password using AWS Cognito. I am so far successful in changing the password using Prompts as given in the documentation. Here is the code

```
var username = document.getElementById('reset-pass').value;
    var data = {
        UserPoolId: _config.cognito.userPoolId,
        ClientId: _config.cognito.clientId
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);

    // setup cognitoUser first
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser({
        Username: username,
        Pool: userPool
    });

cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            console.log('call result: ' + result);
        },
        onFailure: function(err) {
            alert(err);
        },
        inputVerificationCode() {
            var verificationCode = prompt('Please input verification code ' ,'');
            var newPassword = prompt('Enter new password ' ,'');
            cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
        }
    });
```

My question is instead of using prompts, how can I confirm the user on next page. Example 
 On the first page a user enter the email and mail is sent using the `forgotPassword()`. 
 Now user is redirected to a new page. There i wanted to enter the code as well as the new password and call the `cognitoUser.confirmPassword` method.

What i tried is to create a delay interval and after entering the details it would trigger clear interval on button press.

```
   function resetPassword() {
    var username = document.getElementById('reset-pass').value;
    var data = {
        UserPoolId: _config.cognito.userPoolId,
        ClientId: _config.cognito.clientId
    };
    var userPool = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUserPool(data);

    // setup cognitoUser first
    var cognitoUser = new AmazonCognitoIdentity.CognitoUser({
        Username: username,
        Pool: userPool
    });
    // call forgotPassword on cognitoUser
    cognitoUser.forgotPassword({
        onSuccess: function (result) {
            alert("Mail Sent")
        },
        onFailure: function (err) {
            console.log(err)
        },
        inputVerificationCode()
        {
            window.myVar = setInterval(function(){
                console.log('check');
            }, 10000);
            var verificationCode = document.getElementById('code').value;
            var newPassword = document.getElementById('fpass').value;
            cognitoUser.confirmPassword(verificationCode, newPassword, this);
        }
    });
}
```

The HTML Part Of the code-

```
<div class="change">
    <form>
        <label>Enter Email ID</label>
        <input type="email" id="reset-pass" required />
        <br />
        <div class=""><a href="#" class="btn btn_red" id="next" onclick="resetPassword()">Next</a></div>
    </form>
</div>

div class="change-confirm">
<form>
    <label>Enter Code</label>
    <input type="number" id="code" required />
    <br />
    <label>Enter New Password</label>
    <input type="password" id="fpass" required />
    <br />
    <div class=""><a href="#" class="btn btn_red" onclick="clearInterval(window.myVar);"> Reset</a></div>
</form>
</div>
```

But the above code never executed. Instead it stops execution after some time. 
So my question is is there any way to delay the function call of `cognitoUser.confirmPassword` method? I do not want to use prompts instead get the email and code in a text field after mail is sent.

Answer (score 1):

A little late to the party, but it can help someone else.

You can pass the `congitoUser` you have created to the state, and then use `cognitoUser.confirmPassword(...)` by retrieving the cognitoUser object from the state.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using the `aws-amplify-react` which provides a `withAuthenticator` higher-order component that provides a login flow with forgot password, mfa, etc. And it's maintained by a team of devs who work for AWS.

https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/js/react#add-auth

Comment: these components are useless for anything other than default login flow. -> configure ur cognito flow with aws-cli -> deploy generated configuration to the cloud -> install aws-amplify-react -> hook up everything. Result? You are not able to log in due to wrong params beeing required/sent to the cognito. At this point I have installed AWS cognito, which also is broken -> it's not compatible with aws-s3 package, federated ID authentication calls fail. In the end I have installed raw aws-sdk package. And that is the only one works in line with it's own documentation!